# Brewed tea storage safety

Tags: food-safety, storage-lifetime, tea

I'm having a really hard time believing that storing unsweetened, un-drank-from tea in the fridge overnight is unsafe. What gives? I get that a mug that I make wouldn't be sterile, but most non-sterile stuff you can keep for a week. Is it because there's so much water in it?

Comment: where did you see that it is unsafe? That's how many people make iced tea...

Comment: I must be misremembering or confusing with sources for sweetened tea. The paranoid CDC says 8 hours, but other places say 24 for sweetened tea. I think a lot of places when they say "tea" assume sweetened to err on the side of caution.

Comment: Yes, I just saw that CDC recommendation when I was looking this up. With no sugar it will definitely be better. The recommendations are for restaurants and such, which really, really have a responsibility not to get anyone sick, so what you do is up to your own risk tolerance. The article linked [here](http://www.foodsafetynews.com/2010/06/did-you-know-iced-tea-safety) does have a bunch of comments from people who got sick from iced tea, but they all seemed to be using less-safe practices (room temp for hours, for example). On this site it's CDC rules, but what you do is up to you.

Comment: Another common concern with tea safety can also be the lemon wedge added to it.  If the lemon wedge was cross contaminated and then put into your tea it could trouble.  I usually ask for no lemon when getting tea.